# How to get confusion matrix for multi-class semantic segmentation using sklearn.metrics?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am facing this error when trying to get the confusion matrix for a multi-class semantic segmentation problem (for 11 classes). The shape of y_true and y are given below. I have tried the .argmax, but it returns error. can anyone help me to solve this?

```
y_true.shape
(29, 16, 16, 11)

y_pred.shape
(29, 16, 16, 11)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true.argmax(axis=1),y_pred.argmax(axis=1))
print(cf_matrix)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-cea12dc5adac> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
      2 
----> 3 cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true.argmax(axis=1),y_pred.argmax(axis=1))
      4 print(cf_matrix)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    102     # No metrics support "multiclass-multioutput" format
    103     if y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]:
--> 104         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
    105 
    106     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: unknown is not supported
```

Comment: And just how do you imagine this matrix? A separate matrix for each pixel or what?

Comment: one matrix for all the pixels and classes.

Comment: So just flatten the first three dimensions into `7424 x 11`, that should be a plain "multiclass" then. E.g. `y_pred.reshape(-1, 11)`

Answer (score 0):

It works by flattening both your y_pred_argmax and your y_true. This is what I would use:

```
y_pred_argmax = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=3)
y_pred_argmax = np.expand_dims(y_pred_argmax, axis=3) 
y_pred_argmax = to_categorical(y_pred_argmax, num_classes=11)
y_pred_flattened = y_pred_argmax.flatten()
y_flattened = y.flatten()
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_flattened, y_pred_flattened, normalize='true')
```